# Binding to "this" for itemsource?

Tags: xaml, data-binding

Say I have a listbox, whose itemsource is bound to a Collection of classes `Foo`

How can I xaml bind a property directly to the instance of `Foo`?

The property I want to bind is the source of an Image, and the `Foo` class has several properties that influence the source, so in my Converter class. I want `Foo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you have the `ItemsSource` property of an `ListBox` bound to the collection (you don't bind to controls, but to their properties), and you want to show an image for each `Foo` in the collection, you can do it like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding whatever}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Just by leaving the binding's path empty, it is set to the current item.